# Writing the Joint CDF for dependent random variables $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Z$ be such that $P(Z=-1) = P(Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}$. $X,Z$ are independent

Define $Y = XZ$ and write out what the joint CDF of $(X,Y)$ is and determine if $(X,Y)$ is absolutely continuous.

I have already determined that $Y$ is also a standard normal random variable. Additionally $X$ and $Y$ are dependent so is their random vector $(X,Y)$.

If I recall correctly the pair won't be absolutely continuous because of the dependency but maybe I am wrong. Finding a nice pdf seems unlikely because the dependency. Maybe someone can explain that to me.

Trying to write this out we have $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y) = P(X \le x, XZ \le y) $

From here this gives cases where this probability would be zero and non-zero depending on the relation between $x$ and $y$ and whether $Z = 1$ or $-1$

EDIT: Can I write it as $P(X \le x, Y \le y) = \frac{1}{2}P(X \le x \wedge y) + \frac{1}{2}P(X \le x \wedge - y) $

Comment: The question does not even make sense if you don't have independence of $X$ and $Z$. For example if $Z$ is the sign of $X$ then $XZ$ is not normally distributed. It is  a serious mistake to omit indepdenence assumptions.

Comment: My bad for omitting that, they are indeed independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming independence of $X$ an $Z$ we have  $$P(X \leq x, Y\leq y)$$ $$=P(X \leq x, XZ\leq y)=\frac  1 2 P(X\leq x, X\leq y)+\frac  1 2 P(X\leq x, X \geq -y)$$ $$=\frac 1 2 P(X \leq x \wedge y)+\frac 1  2 P(-y \leq X \leq x).$$ [Note that $-X \leq y$ iff $X \geq -y$].

The joint distribution is not absolutely continuous becsue it is concentrated on the union of the lines $\{(x,y): y=x\}$ and $\{(x,y): y=-x\}$ and the Lebesgue measure of this union is $0$. Hence the distribition is singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Because I can write this in terms of pdf/cdf of $X$, do I actually have the vector is jointly absolutely continuous?

Comment: @oliverjones See my answer now.